# Delete lines from a file thanks to variables coming from an other file with AWK or SED

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I would like to delete each line in `data.txt` which contains one of the parameters of the second column in `keys.txt` file.

- `keys.txt`

  ```
  2 aa
  2 bb
  2 cc
  2 dd
  ```
- `data.txt`

  ```
  1 aa It is great
  1 aa I want to delete this line
  1 kk Really ?
  1 bb Yes, I think so.
  1 bb Why ?
  1 kk Because I don't like the current situation
  1 ll I want to change
  1 cc Indeed it's a need
  1 cc Sorry
  1 zz Ok !
  ```
- Desired output

  ```
  1 kk Really ?
  1 kk Because I don't like the current situation
  1 ll I want to change
  1 zz Ok !
  ```

I tried with the following `awk` program:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {pattern[$0]; next}
    {
        for (var in pattern) {
            if ($0 ~ var) {
                getline
                next
            }
        }
        print >> GoodFile.txt
    }
' keys.txt
```

Comment: Do you really want to match anywhere on the line? This would remove a line with the word `aardvark` since that contains `aa`. Your data suggest that you only want to remove a line from `data.txt` *if the second field of that line matches one of the second fields in `keys.txt`*. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I do not yet see a question here ... However terdon already addressed this: You should use `pattern[$2]` in your `NR==FNR` block, and `if ($2==var)` in the `for` loop to guard against the case that the parameters themselves contain RegExp special characters. Also, you have to add `data.txt` as argument to your `awk` call.

Comment: Yes it's for the second field. But I would like to do the same thing more quickly if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are already close, only missing a few minor points:

- You need to add `data.txt` as argument to your `awk` call, otherwise that file will not be processed.
- You are currently registering the entire line in `keys.txt` to your removal database, so you should restrict that to the second field (`$2` instead of `$0`).
- You are using `if ($0 ~ var)` to check if a line in `data.txt` should be excluded. Here too, you should only compare the second field of the line, and you should use the exact match (`==`) instead of regular expression match to guard against situations in which your keys can contain characters that are special to regular expressions.
- You print from `awk`, which you actually don't need to. You can redirect the output instead.

So, with slight modifications:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{pattern[$2];next} !($2 in pattern)' keys.txt data.txt > GoodFile.txt
```

This will register the second column of each line in `keys.txt` in the array `pattern`, but do nothing else for that file. For `data.txt`, it will reach the point where the `!($2 in pattern)` condition is evaluated for each line. If the condition evaluates to "true" (i.e. the second column of the line is *not* among the indices of the array `pattern`), the current line will be printed.

Comment: Is there any benefit to using shell redirection over printing in `awk`? I mean apart from the obvious: it is shorter, more concise and more adaptable, but is it also somehow more efficient?

Comment: @terdon Not sure, actually. Ed Morton would probably know ...

Comment: I'm not as much expert as EdMorton is, but AFAIK there is no big difference except that awk single `>` redirection for whole input act same as its append `>>` redirection. for example when you do `{for(i=1; i<=10; i++) print >"output"}` it always working in append mode which is differ from shell `>` redirection when we use within loop like `for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)); do echo $i >output; done`; first would print all numbers 1 to 10 while shell redirection will only keep last number 10. that's because awk keep the output file open until all inputs read. [...]

Comment: .... personally I would never use awk redirection for writing to a single file cases and will use for a specifc cases where we want to write to different output files based on specifc condition which then awk print would be useful enough

Comment: @terdon There's a small performance hit for doing the redirection within awk because then awk has to know about the output file and track it's been opened/closed but more importantly IMHO there's a functional difference - for example, if you redirect the output within awk to a non-writable file then awk will do everything else up till that print statement is hit before failing (which if you're doing calculations on a TB file and printing the result in the END section would be less than ideal!) whereas if you redirect the output outside of awk then the script won't run at all.

Comment: FWIW I'd only redirect output (or input) within an awk script if it's necessary, thereby leaving the file manipulation to the shell which does it best. The exception is that I'd always let awk open the input file rather than the shell (i.e. `awk 'script' file` instead of `awk 'script' < file`) because the latter robs you of the availability of the input file name in FILENAME and it's not extensible to having multiple input files. The tradeoff to that is that `awk 'script' file > out` will zap the output file even if the input file can't be opened, unlike `awk 'script' < file > out`.

Comment: @αғsнιη [you're close](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621506/delete-lines-from-a-file-thanks-to-variables-coming-from-an-other-file-with-awk/621564#comment1162362_621510) but `>` in awk isn't quite the same as `>>` in shell as it's not always working in append mode. `>` in awk will overwrite the output file on the first write and append to it afterwards so it's like if in shell you did `while read foo; do echo "$foo"; done > file` as opposed to if in shell you did `while read foo; do echo "$foo" >> file; done`. The latter is equivalent to what you get in awk with `>>`.

Answer (score 5):

The first problem in your script is this:

```
NR == FNR {pattern[$0]; next}
```

You are using the whole line as a key for the `pattern` array, but you only want the second field. You don't need both `next` and `getline`, all you want is `next` to move to the next line. You also forgot to pass the second file as input. Finally, you need to quote the file name since it is just a string, not a variable. Fixing these two errors produces:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {pattern[$2]; next}
    {
        for (var in pattern) {
            if ($0 ~ var) {
                getline
                next
            }
        }
        print >> "GoodFile.txt"
    }
' keys.txt data.txt
```

Now, are you *sure* you want `>>` there? That means that `awk` will not overwrite anything that was already in the file (the output of a previous run, for example). You don't need the `>>` if you just want `awk` to not overwrite its own output from a single run, `>` is enough. You only need `>>` if you want to keep data from previous runs, which I suspect you do not.

Also, based on your data, you don't actually want to check the entire line. You just want to skip lines in `data.txt` whose second field is the same as a second field from `keys.txt`. If so, this would be far more efficient, especially for larger files:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {pattern[$2]; next}
    {
        if ($2 in pattern) {
            next
        }
        print > "GoodFile.txt"
    }
' keys.txt data.txt
```

Or, the equivalent but more concise:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {pattern[$2]; next}
    {
        if (!($2 in pattern) {
            print > "GoodFile.txt"
        }
    }
' keys.txt data.txt
```

Comment: Also, `!($2 in pattern) {print > "GoodFile.txt"}` is the "awkish" syntax here, as this is the only condition to test for this code block.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks, fixed. I'll keep the `if` though since I find it clearer.

Comment: you use already FNR==NR, why not if (FNR==NR) too? :) ok I can accept the readability reason, as the first condition FNR==NR has become a meme.

Comment: @thanasisp ha! Very fair point. Because, as you say, I'm used to it. To be perfectly honest, I keep getting confused about when the `if` is needed and when not, so I simply usually default to using it.

Answer (score 0):

`GNU sed` with the extended regex mode turned ON `-E` and autoprint pattern space turned OFF `-n`

```
$ sed -En '
    /^\S+\s+(\S+)$/{
      s//\1/;H;d
    }
    G
    /^\S+\s+(\S+)\s.*\n\1(\n|$)/!P
' keys.txt data.txt
```

Assuming that keys file has two fields and data file more than two.

As a first step, we store in the hold the 2nd field of the keys.txt file. Then when reading the data.txt file we append the keys to the current record of data.txt file and make a comparison whether the 2nd field of data could be seen anywhere amongst the keys. Only if not found do we print data.